# absolute positioning layout - vertical center over previous div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A simplified version of my problem is that I want to center a 'text' div over an 'image' div on screen mode, but position them underneath each other on mobile.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <article> </article>

  <div class="text-cell">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <h3>Category</h3>
  </div>  
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
}

article { 
   height: 350px;
   width: 100%;
   border-top: 1px solid #000;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;    
}

.text-cell {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.text-cell {
  position: relative;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1);
}

}
```

This is the closest I got. It puts the 'text-cell' overtop of article at screen size and underneath on mobile size.

I want it to be vertically centred over the 'article' on screen size, as it resizes. 'text-cell' doesn't have a defined size, and Ideally I'd like article to be a percentage or a more responsive size, but that isn't as important.

EDIT - this html is part of a Wordpress loop, meaning it is generated a certain amount of times, and each one is stacked under the other. (for ex. 3 copies of < div class="wrapper" > stacked)

What I am going for

[image]

Comment: provide a jsfiddle please and then we can help

Comment: take out that php crap , we have no idea what classes that is adding and what the background looks like ,   we have no idea what is in the artice, you need to copy the rendered html not the htlm with php in there

Comment: edited my answer without the php, it doesn't affect my desired outcome. I am not familiar with jsfiddle

Comment: we didn't know it didn't effect it really

Comment: basically the php added a specific background image to article. That is why article has a specific size applied to it, since it is essentially empty, but I want it to show the Background image in full

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i'd recommend doing is placing that `.text-cell` div above the article, that way, on mobile, it's statically where you want it to be placed, following the document natural hierarchy. This is what i've done in the code snippet (i've also changed its position to `static` inside the media query.)

Having said that, i would personally consider changing the structure of the HTML to have more semantic meaning (for example, placing the `h2` & `h3` tags inside a `header` tag and place that inside your `article` tag.)

If you want help doing that, explain what you're trying to achieve inside the article, and i'm happy to help you achieve what you're looking for.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
article {
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.text-cell {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .text-cell {
    position: static;
    border-top: solid 1px #000;
    background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-cell">
    <h2><a href="" rel="bookmark">The title</a></h2>
    <h3>The category</h3>
  </div>

  <article style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/300x300');">

  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my answer a bit, Basically trying to achieve what this company has done on their home page http://redantler.com. The titles are over the 'rows' but when you scale the page, the text div goes underneath the image

Comment: having it after the article is where i'd like it statically place on mobile. My code works almost good, except I only got the 'text-cell' to go over top the  article and align to the bottom. I want it to center over the article

Comment: added a pic to help illustrate what I'm going for